# Content Testing Thumbnail 403 error in Azure

Tags: content-testing

Locally I can start a content test and preview the variant thumbnails no problem. 
 In `Sitecore 9.1.1 Azure PaaS`single instance environment all I see are 403 errors instead of the thumbnails.

[image]

I have checked through obvious config settings and everything seems to be enabled.
[image]

The executable path looks a little strange - but am struggling to find if this needs to be changed for Azure instance.

There is nothing in the console Network tab as to what the 403 is - whether the thumbnails are not being generated, or they were but can't be accessed.

Nothing obvious in the log, and Phantomjs.exe is located in the `app_Data\tools` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this feature is supported.  In the Test environment where it wasn't working it was related to the Azure WAF blocking the content for some reason.  Then it worked fine in UAT and Production (which was under a different WAF).

Answer (score 3):

It's unsupported. By Microsoft, so by extension that would mean Sitecore as well.

Azure PaaS runs in what they call a `sandbox`. It's a restricted environment that only supports in part, what you would normally be able to do in your application.

In the [list of unsupported frameworks for the sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks), we find

> Other scenarios that are not supported:
>
> - PhantomJS/Selenium: tries to connect to local address, and also uses
>     GDI+.

As such, I don't think you're doing anything wrong. It just doesn't appear possible.

You would probably need to reach out to Sitecore Support for alternatives or to inquire about a workaround.

Comment: Interesting thanks! Not sure how content testing is supposed to work in Azure without being able to see a preview then :)  Hopefully my support ticket gets a response soon.